# Base table or view not found custom database

Tags: magento-1.8, module, database, frontend, sql

It seams I can't get the table from my custom database.

My module should list all data from the database frontend(and backend later)
But I get this error

> a:5:{i:0;s:93:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'ifp.mage_emailorder' doesn't exist";i:1;s:4318:"#0
>   /var/www/ifp.dk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

What I can read on the net. Eather its the database setup, or the block I use to call it out.

**Database setup**

**app/code/local/Puk/EmailOrder/sql/emailorder_setup/mysql-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$sql=<<<SQLTEXT
create table emailorder(
    emailorder_id int not null auto_increment, 
    order_date varchar(255) not null,
    product_name varchar(255) not null,
    location varchar(255) not null,
    date_for varchar(255) not null,
    name_title varchar(100) not null,
    email varchar(255) not null,
    company varchar(255) not null,
    adress varchar(255) not null,
    zipcode varchar(255) not null,
    city varchar(255) not null,
    phone varchar(255) not null,
    comment text not null,
    order_done int not null default 0,
    primary key(emailorder_id)

);


SQLTEXT;

$installer->run($sql);
//demo 
//Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')->setId(null);
//demo 
$installer->endSetup();
```

**The block**

**app/code/local/EmailOrder/Block/Monblock.php**

```
<?php
class Puk_EmailOrder_Block_Monblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
     public function methodblock()
     {

        $retour='';
     $collection = Mage::getModel('emailorder/emailorder')->getCollection()
                                 ->setOrder('emailorder_id','asc');

        foreach($collection as $data)
        {
             $retour .= $data->getData('product_name').' '.$data->getData('location')
                     .' '.$data->getData('date_for').'<br />';
         }

         Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('YES!');
         return $retour;
      }
}
```

Can someone help? :)

Comment: Please update the contents of your config.xml file in question. Can you see the table created in DB directly ?

Comment: The config.xml file says "emailorder" and in the db it is also "emailorder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have table prefixes setup in your Magento installation and you created table with SQL as `emailorder`. When you are calling code `Mage::getModel('emailorder/emailorder')`, Magento is searching for the table named 'mage_emailorder' because of the prefixes.

Drop your table and re-run the code for setup either via Magento way, or add the prefix so that table name becomes `mage_emailorder` in your SQL query. As a dirty work-around, you can directly modify the table in DB, just rename it to `mage_emailorder`.

Comment: Nice! now i dont get the error. But it still dont write the data from the database. Can you tell me why??

Comment: Dont bother, it was a typo. :)